# Changing and image "src" to a cached image causes a strange flicker

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In a page, we have an image that is replaced by another one after having been moved. It's a simple map navigation interface.

It works approximately like this (sorry for not being able to show you the real code or an example but it is a private web site) :

```
var imgMap = document.getElementById('myimage');
var imgMapTemp;
...
<the user moves the image around, and this triggers the loading of the new one>
...
function loadnewimage() {
  imgMapTemp = new Image();
  imgMapTemp.onload = function() 
  {
    updateimage();
  }
  imgMapTemp.src = 'someurl';
}

function updateimage() {
  imgMap.style.top = 0;
  imgMap.style.left = 0;
  imgMap.src = imgMapTemp.src;
}
```

What happens is that the old image is shown again for a very brief instant before the new one.

It did not happen some time ago. It started happening with Chrome and now it happens in all the latest versions of the browser, so I wonder whether this could be caused by optimizations in JavaScript engines?

Comment: quite possibly. Test in other browsers to be sure.

Comment: It happens in Chrome (current) and Firefox versions 4 and up (maybe earlier, not sure). It does not happen in IE8, nor in the latest Safari or Opera. I have no IE9 (we are running Windows XP).

Comment: Edit : We found an older Firefox and confirm that it did not happen in FF 3.6, so it happens since FF uses the Jägermonkey JS engine.

Comment: Any advice on how to avoid this flickering is still very welcome.

Comment: As this is a map - you can try loading images (even further) offscreen. So the flicker would be happening outside of visible map area.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I didn't get a notification of your comment. That could work indeed. It would make the code more complex though...

Comment: Just thought about it again, but that would not work. The old image remains visible until it is replaced by the new one. That cannot happen offscreen.

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Comment: No sorry I've never been able to solve this. It happens erratically so it's very hard to debug. Some computers show this behaviour, others don't. Same OS same browser same hardware (corporate computers), so very difficult to narrow down to something specific.